# Separation of variables and basis of solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> If a PDE can be solved by separation of variables. Then the superposition of the solutions found via this method can form **all** other solutions to the PDE.

Is this statement correct? If it is please can you explain why and if it isn't could you also explain why.

Comment: For certain types of pde's we can use the method you have mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is correct only when the PDE is linear.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a proof or source so I can look it up in more detail?